# Show that $x_{(n)}=0\space\space\forall \space\space\space n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and the following differential equation:
>
> $$x''-2ax'+bx=0.$$
>
> with $x(0)=x(1)=0.$
>
> Show that $x(n)=0\space\space\forall \space\space\space n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried to make a substitution and guess a solution $x=e^{rt}$ but then I can't prove the statement. Any hints/ideas?

Comment: Is $x_{(n)}$ the $n$-derivative of $x$ or the value of $x$ at $n$?

Comment: Why are $(0),(1),(n)$ in subscript? Do they indicate something other than the value of $x$ at $0,1,n$?

Comment: @jobe Umm, no, they are the value of $x$ at $n$, I will edit this to make it more clear.

Comment: I have removed the [second-order-logic] tag, since it's not relevant to second-order differential equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation is $$\lambda^2-2a\lambda+b=0$$if the distinct **real** roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ exist we can write$$x=pe^{\lambda_1t}+1e^{\lambda_2t}$$by substitution we obtain $$p+q=0\\pe^{\lambda_1}+qe^{\lambda_2}=0$$which yields to $$p=q=0$$and $$x(t)=0\quad,\quad t\in \Bbb R$$ hence the desired result.

If $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$ then we have $$x=(p+qt)e^{\lambda t}$$therefore $$p=0\\p+q=0$$from which we again obtain $$x(t)=0\quad,\quad t\in \Bbb R$$

If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are complex conjugate and unreal roots, let $$\lambda_1=\alpha+\beta i\\\lambda_2=\alpha-\beta i$$ therefore $$x(t)=e^{\alpha t}(p\sin\beta t+q\cos\beta t)$$by imposing initial condition we obtain $$q=0\\p\sin \beta=0$$ if $\beta =l\pi$ for some $l\in \Bbb Z$ then $$x(t)=pe^{\alpha t}\sin l\pi t$$which shows that $$x(n)=0\quad,\quad n\in \Bbb Z$$ if not, then $\sin \beta\ne 0$ and we have $p=0$ which leads to $x(t)=0$ hence the result.

Comment: Thank you. Right on time feedback!

Comment: Why is that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ yields to $x=(p+qx)e^{\lambda t}$ why is that $qx$?

Comment: It should be $qt$

Comment: Thank you . That was useful feedback....

Answer (score 1):

You get $r^2-2ar+b=0$. This gives $r=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-b}$, giving the general solution as $$x=\begin{cases}c_1e^{t(a+\sqrt{a^2-b})}+c_2e^{t(a-\sqrt{a^2-b})},&a^2>b\\(c_1+c_2t)e^{at},&a^2=b\\e^{at}\big[c_1\cos(t\sqrt{b-a^2})+c_2\sin(t\sqrt{b-a^2})\big],&a^2<b\end{cases}$$You are given $x(0)=0=x(1)$, which give $x=0$ as the only solution for the first two cases.

For the third case, note that we get $c_1=0=c_2\sin(\sqrt{b-a^2})$. This gives $c_2=0$ or $\sqrt{b-a^2}=n\pi,n\in\Bbb N$. The possible solutions are $x=ke^{at}\sin(n \pi t),k\in\Bbb R$. Now, note that $x(m)=ke^{an}\sin(mn\pi)=0\ \ \forall m\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: How about $x=\sin(\pi t)$ with $a=0$, $b=\pi^2$? (This is not a counterexample to the OP's claim, but doesn't fit your claim for case 2).

Comment: Yes, I am adding that part

Comment: Can you add more details about how you obtained the third case?

Comment: @C.Cristi As in how I got $e^{at}\big[c_1\cos(t\sqrt{b-a^2})+c_2\sin(t\sqrt{b-a^2})\big]$ or how I got $c_2\sin(\sqrt{b-a^2})=0$?

Comment: As in how you got $e^{at}....$

Comment: @C.Cristi If $a^2<b, r=a\pm i\sqrt{b-a^2}\implies x=c_1e^{t(a+i\sqrt{b-a^2})}+c_2e^{t(a-i\sqrt{b-a^2})}=e^{at}\big[c_1e^{it\sqrt{b-a^2}}+c_2e^{-it\sqrt{b-a^2}}\big]$. Using $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, we get$$x=e^{at}\big[(c_1+c_2)\cos(t\sqrt{b-a^2})+(c_1-c_2)i\sin(t\sqrt{b-a^2})\big]=e^{at}\big[k_1\cos(t\sqrt{b-a^2})+k_2\sin(t\sqrt{b-a^2})\big]$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution not requiring explicitly solving the equation. General theory tells us that a solution to such an equation is determined by its value and value of its derivative at a point. In particular, if $x'(1)=0$, then $x$ is constant zero function, so assume $x'(1)\neq 0$.

Consider $y(t)=\frac{x'(0)}{x'(1)}x(t+1)$. Then it's easy to see $y$ satisfies the same equation as $x$. Further, $y(0)=x(1)=0$ and $y'(0)=\frac{x'(0)}{x'(1)}x'(1)=x'(0)$, from which it follows $y(t)=x(t)$. We can now say $0=x(1)=y(1)=x(1+1)=x(2)$, i.e. $x(2)=0$. We can now finish with induction (note that you have treat negative numbers separately).